# How many option values can be in option in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart 1.5.6.4. I stuck on strange issue. Lemme tell you about that a bit.

I added 16 options in the option tab without option values and when I tried adding the 17th option in the option tab it didn't let me do so. I deleted one and then tried with other and it is added successfully. In short i can't add more than 16 options in option tab in product page.

So my first question is that -> what I assuming is it true as i can't add the 17th option here.

Also Inside product in option tab under how many values can i can define for one option.

My question is that is there any limitation in the number of option values for option?  If yes then how many, and can increase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on options or option values in Opencart.  In all likelihood you are hitting a limit on the php `post_max_size` directive.  Depending on your server configuration you might be able to increase it in a local php.ini file, in .htaccess, or if not contact your server admin and ask them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines to my `php.ini` file in the root & admin folder and the problem is solved!

```
max_input_vars = 50000;

suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000;

suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000;

max_input_nesting_level = 256;

upload_max_filesize = 256M;

max_input_time = 60;
```